# Multiple matBadge on MatIcon

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to have an icon surrounded by two badges, one on the top left and one on the bottom right.

```
  <span matBadge="1" matBadgePosition="above before" matBadgeSize="large" class="stepNumber">
    <span matBadge="favorite" matBadgePosition="below after" matBadgeSize="large" class="stepSubIcon">
      <mat-icon class="stepIcon">toggle_on</mat-icon>
    </span>
  </span>

    .stepNumber {
  .mat-badge-content {
    background-color: white;
    color: dark;
    border: 1px solid dark;
  }
}

.stepSubIcon {
  .mat-badge-content {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    background-color: white;
    color: dark;
    border: 0px;
  }
}

.stepIcon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: dark;
  color: white;
  height: 80px;
  width:80px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

When only one span has a badge, it appears in the correct place. When both spans have their badge, the matBadgePosition is no longer taken into account.

Is it possible to have several badges surrounding an icon?

Comment: Please share a working example or stackblitz, if possible some images of how you want the output to be?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to reproduce via stackblitz, but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below separates the material badges using the icon itself, this should solve your issue

```html
<span
    matBadge="1"
    matBadgePosition="above before"
    matBadgeSize="large"
    class="stepNumber"
    >
    <mat-icon class="heystepIcon">toggle_on</mat-icon>
    <span
      matBadge="favorite"
      matBadgePosition="below after"
      matBadgeSize="large"
      class="stepSubIcon"
    ></span> 
</span>
```

Comment: thank you, the second badge is in the place I wanted  !